# Jquery substring lookup

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

I have a JQuery using for OBIEE 11g. I am trying to hover text to return ajax call using json. I can read texts with single td class. 
Example  `<td class="PTCHC1>headcount</td>`

I want to also read text

```
<td class="FilterCell">Headcount is not equal to / is not in</td>
```

using  **is**  as the delimiter.

Here is what I am trying to do but I think I am not doing it correctly.

```
jQ(document).on("mouseenter.dataCookbook_Hover", 
    "[class*='TTHC'], [class^='PTCHC'], [class^='PTRHC'] , [class='TitleCell'] , [class='FilterCell']
     .text(string.substring(string.indexOf('is')))", handleMouseOver);
```

Comment: Can you format the code? it is very confusing :)

Comment: Please explain in more detail exactly what you expect this code to do. Currently the code doesn't make sense and problem description isn't very concise. Also show the declaration for `handleMouseOver`

Comment: Are you having an issue with the string filtering? i.e. using text.substr(text.indexOf('is')) OR is it grabbing the DOM element? If it's indexOf then it will return the first point in the string of "is", if you need an array then you want text.split('is')

Comment: yes, i am trying to grab the substring where first point of is located.

Comment: <tr>
<td class="FilterOpCell"> </td>
<td class="FilterCell">Headcount is not equal to / is not in <Span class="FilterValueSpan">1</Span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
`<td class="FilterOpCell">and</td>
<td class="FilterCell">Headcount is not equal to / is not in <Span class="FilterValueSpan">1</Span></td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 0):

```
//create an element containing just the first chunk of those text nodes
$(".FilterCell:contains(is)").each(function() {
    var $me = $(this);
    var pieces = $me.text().split('is');
    $me.empty().append('<span class="hover-action">' + pieces[0] + '</span>')
       .append(pieces.slice(1).join('is');
}
//then include those new elements in your selector
$(document).on("mouseenter.dataCookbook_Hover", 
"[class*='TTHC'], [class^='PTCHC'], [class^='PTRHC'], .TitleCell, .FilterCell .hover-action", handleMouseOver);
```

Comment: This is not working since there might be multiple is in the same td class. Sample HTML 
 <tr>
<td class="FilterOpCell"> </td>
<td class="FilterCell">Headcount is not equal to / is not in <Span class="FilterValueSpan">1</Span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="FilterOpCell">and</td>
<td class="FilterCell">Headcount is not equal to / is not in <Span class="FilterValueSpan">1</Span></td>
</tr>

Comment: @zaman then you need to split on the text 'is' in the handler.  I'll give an example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to see your example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the example. I just need to grab anything before 1st _is_ appearance in the TD class. 

Also, I need to integrate the code with the existing code since I am grabbing other TD class values as well. 

That's why i wanted to do something similar to _[class='FilterCell']
     .text(string.substring(string.indexOf('is')))"_

Comment: You can't select part of a node, so you'd need to wrap "Headcount" in your example in something (probably a span). You could do that before you register your hover handler and add that class to the selector.  I'll edit the example to show what I mean.